# Lollipop Button with custom background color

Tags: android, button

I want to use Lollipop Button with custom background color like the buttons (Force stop and uninstall) in following picture. When I use

```
<Button
    android:background="#F44336"
    .... />
```

the ripple effect, shadow and elevation are gone. And I cannot use two different colors by adding style. Is there anyway to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: did you set an elevation?

Comment: no, it's the default animation include in android sdk.

Comment: so you do or do not want elevation and ripple?

Comment: I want those effects. But when I use android:background="" those effects are gone.

Comment: you have to set the elevation and create your own ripple I believe

Comment: use tint, not background color

Comment: Thanks, this should be the answer. Using tint works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a drawable to create a ripple effect and set a background color.

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">

    <!-- Note: <ripple> acts like a layer-list -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <!-- This color is not displayed in any way -->
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- This is the border -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f0600000"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#f00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

 </ripple>
```

Put in in `drawable` folder and set it as your button's background.

Comment: After adding this, ripple works. How about elevation like the default button.

Comment: there is no ripple effect on pre-lollipop devices in general. they do not support low level RenderScript which makes rippling and reveal effects so performant.